# is "Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible" a bug?

Tags: typescript

This type-checks in [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Afunction%20head(%5Ba%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20a%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%5D%2C%20%5B2%5D%5D.map(head)%0D%0A), but fails on v3.1.6:

```
function head([a]) {
  return a;
}

const x: number[] = [[1], [2]].map(head)
```

Error mesage:

```
server/src/mock-resolvers/mock-data.ts(549,36): error TS2345: Argument of type '([a]: [any]) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number[], index: number, array: number[][]) => any'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[any]'.
      Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.
```

Is this a bug? I don't understand the error message or see what's wrong with the code.

Being more specific with the types doesn't help, I get a similar error if the function is defined like this:

```
function head([a, _b]: [number, number]): number {
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reproduce the error if you enable `strictFunctionTypes` in the playground. You can read more about this option [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) but the gist of it is that it removes bi-variance from functions.

In your case the array `[[1], [2]]` is not typed as `Array<[number]>`, but rather it is typed as `Array<number[]>`, since typescript does not infer tuple types for array literals unless it is directed to do so. This causes an error because your function is explicit about accepting a the tuple type `[any]`. An array type is not assignable to a tuple with a single element (even a tuple of `any`).

The simplest solution is to specify the type of the array explicitly:

```
function head([a] : [number]) { // type is not required but it's best to not leave implict any 
  return a;
}

const data: Array<[number]> = [[1], [2]]
const x: number[] = data.map(head)
```

You can create a helper function that will infer tuples from the argument type:

```
function tuple<T extends any[]>(...a: T) {
  return a;
}

const x: number[] = [tuple(1), tuple(2)].map(head)
```

Or infer directly an array of tuples:

```
function tupleArray<T extends [any]|any[]>(...a: T[]) {
  return a;
}

const x: number[] = tupleArray([1], [2]).map(head)
```

Comment: The suggested fix is almost the same as my second example. Both fail in the playground with `strictFunctionTypes`: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Afunction%20head(%5Ba%5D%20%3A%20%5Bnumber%5D)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20type%20is%20not%20required%20but%20it's%20best%20to%20not%20leave%20implict%20any%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20a%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%5D%2C%20%5B2%5D%5D.map(head)%0D%0A

Comment: @MaxHeiber the sugeste fix is not to type the `head` function .. I just included that for the sake of good practice. The problem is with the type of the array literal. Putting it in another variable ang typing it explicitly as `Array<[number]>` is the proposed fix (the first one I mean)

Comment: ah! sorry about my reading comprehension. Fixed like this:
`const x: number[] = ([[1], [2]] as [number][]).map(head)`