# Infer prop types from provider component when composing context providers in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to use a trick (similar to [example1](https://github.com/HorusGoul/react-component-pack), [example2](https://github.com/scottjr632/react-provider-wrapper)) to deal with React Provider hell, so instead of this

```
<ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
  <FeatureFlags flags={myFlags}>
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider>
        <HttpClientProvider baseUrl="https://...">
          <UnitProvider>
            <CustomerProvider>
              <HistoryProvider>
                <App />
              </HistoryProvider>
            </CustomerProvider>
          </UnitProvider>
        </HttpClientProvider>
      </RouterProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </FeatureFlags>
</ThemeProvider>
```

it can be done like this:

```
    <Provide
      providers={[
        [ThemeProvider, { theme: defaultTheme }],
        [FeatureFlags , { flags: myFlags }],
        AuthProvider,
        RouterProvider,
        [HttpClientProvider, {baseUrl: 'https://...'}],
        UnitProvider,
        CustomerProvider,
        HistoryProvider,
      ]}
    >
      <App />
    </Provide>
```

The `Provide` component is pretty straight forward and looks like this

```
export function Provide<T extends React.ComponentType>({
  children,
  providers,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  providers: (
    | React.ComponentType
    | [T, Omit<React.ComponentProps<T>, 'children'>]
  )[];
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {providers.reduceRight((componentTree, cfg) => {
        const [Provider, props] = Array.isArray(cfg) ? cfg : [cfg, {}];
        return <Provider {...props}>{componentTree}</Provider>;
      }, children)}
    </>
  );
}
```

I would like to achieve some typings help with TS (eg when I make a typo `[FeatureFlags, { flagggsss: myFlags }]`), But it infers correctly type only from the first provider (ThemeProvider) and uses it to check types for the other providers (eg fails on `FeatureFlags` provider because `ThemeProvider` doesn't have property `flags`).

I was trying to solve this with some `infer` magic from TypeScript, but with no success. Is it possible to provide typings for `providers` in the way that TS could infer prop types for each provider correctly?

#### Sidenote:

I know I can achieve the same result in another way, like

```
      providers={[
        ({children}) => <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>{children}</FeatureFlags>
        ({children}) => <FeatureFlags flags={myFlags}>{children}</FeatureFlags>,
        AuthProvider,
        RouterProvider,
        ...
      ]}
```

But I'm more interested if the type script can infer the prototypes of providers.

Comment: I'm blanking on this right now.  Each element of the array is `type ProviderArgs<C> = C extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? ({} extends P ? C : never) | [C, Omit<P, 'children'>] : never;`  But how do I make an array where each element has a different generic...

Comment: @LindaPaiste this looks promising :)

Comment: It seems to be a typing issue with nested array that cannot be infered as array of tuples (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284478/is-types-of-parameters-0-and-value-are-incompatible-a-bug).

Anyway I ended up with `<Provider providers={[children => <Provider a={a} children={children}/>]}/>` that seems anyway more readable.